# how to set navigation drawer in bottom to up

Tags: android, button, navigation

I want create navigation drawer in the bottom , when click button open navigation in bottom to up

like this in link

http://imgh.us/Screenshot_2015-08-13-21-27-20_1.png

Comment: This is not how the provided Navigation drawer works. You will have to create your own custom implementation

Comment: Yea, that is going to require some custom view/animation work.

Comment: Thanks , I'm false andrstand this photo

Answer (score 1):

The default Navigation drawer does not work that way. Consider using 
https://github.com/wunderlist/android-sliding-layer-lib

It allows you to configure a view/layout(with your content) that can slide into your screen from any direction.

Answer (score 1):

This answer may be too late for the original asker, but you could get this effect by using a Sliding Drawer. It has since been deprecated, however, there are some nice open source alternatives around, like the ones in the links below:

https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel

https://github.com/wunderlist/android-sliding-layer-lib

https://github.com/Ali-Rezaei/SlidingDrawer